# Why does the X2go client start an ssh daemon?

Tags: x2go

I've been using X2go client on a windows machine to connect to a linux server for several years. Now I want to understand it a little better.  I notice that when I open the session manager, an sshd process starts.  What role does this play?

Answer (score 1):

X2Go uses SSH for its transport protocol. See here for a description of the product features:
https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:newtox2go

> Basic features of X2Go  [*emphasis added; sorry, I can't figure out how to embed bullets in quotes*]

- Graphical Remote Desktop that works well over both low bandwidth and
- high bandwidth connections
  The ability to disconnect and reconnect to a session, even from another client
- Support for sound
- Support for as many simultaneous users as the computer's resources will support (NX3 free edition limited you to 2.)
- **Traffic is securely tunneled over SSH**
- File Sharing from client to server
- Printer Sharing from client to server
- Easily select from multiple desktop environments (e.g., MATE, GNOME, KDE)
- Remote support possible via Desktop Sharing
- The ability to access single applications by specifying the name of the desired executable in the client configuration or selecting
  one of the pre-defined common applications

Note that some of these features, like file/printer sharing bidirectionally aren't possible for a client connection, so a sshd process is started so that the server can connect back to the client to support bidirectional processes.

Comment: The last sentence seems relevant to the question.  Still hoping someone knows more...

Comment: Since I can set up either local or remote port forwarding from the ssh client, it is not immediately obvious that the server really needs this.